# Android Generate APK KeyStore File

Tags: android

I am working for a client on their Android app. I need to create an APK file which will be deployed to the client's server.

The client does not have the original KeyStore file! In Android Studio it says that the KeyStore file is required! What can I do?

Comment: Build->"Generate Signed APK...".  Select the project in the wizard and under "Key store path:" select "Create new...".  Fill out everything and it will generate a keystore for you.  Everyone who has the previous app will have to delete it and reinstall with the new.  You can't update with a different key.

Answer (score 0):

if exists a previous version of the app it can´t be updated because need the same Keystore file, Now you need to create another Keystore to sign your app.

[Generate a KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html)

[Signing your applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)